# How to post raw text from sim900 module?

Tags: embedded, gsm, sim900

I am trying to post a raw text from a sim900 module for which I have set the content type already but I am unable to figure out the documentation on how to send the actualy content inside my code.

`AT+CGATT=1
AT+SAPBR=3,1,CONTYPE,GPRS
AT+SAPBR=3,1,APN,internet
AT+SAPBR=1,1
AT+SAPBR=0,1
AT+HTTPTERM
AT+SAPBR=2,1
AT+HTTPINIT
AT+HTTPPARA=CID,1
AT+HTTPPARA=CONTENT, text/plain;charset=UTF-8
AT+HTTPPARA=URL,http://requestb.in/zl1ngazl`

How can I send the actual POST body to the url in order for me to be able to process the data at the other end. I am able to receive queries in the url but have had no success with what to put up on the body.

Any advice would be appreciated as I have come up to a dead end on this.

Comment: Simcom provides a manual for [HTTPS AT commands](http://simcom.ee/documents/SIM900/SIM900_HTTPS%20AT%20Command%20Set_V1%2000.pdf) and I assume this part should be similar for HTTP.

According to this manual the body can be sent using `AT+HTTPDATA` but I haven't got such a module in my hands yet.

Comment: You might also want to look at [this description](http://www.raviyp.com/embedded/194-sim900-gprs-http-at-commands).